# Chrome: Save web.whatsapp.com as html - smileys missing

Tags: html, google-chrome, whatsapp

I would like to save my web.whatsapp.com chat history. With google chrome and `right-click > Save as.. > Format: Webpage, Complete` i can download the html file. That way pictures of the chat history are included but smileys are missing.

I do not really have a clue about html - what i figured out so far is that the smileys are stored in one big image file that is accessible via: [blob:https%3A//web.whatsapp.com/233563d6-722b-483a-835c-c9907f1d9c42](http://blob:https%3A//web.whatsapp.com/233563d6-722b-483a-835c-c9907f1d9c42)
when you have web.whatsapp.com open.

What i am struggling with is how to store this file in the html directory in order to get the smileys in the offline version. Any help and advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different smileys are actually stored in the html-file

```
<img alt="" draggable="false" class="emoji emojiordered0606 selectable-text" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">
```

To get them back in the offline version you only have to get rid of `<img alt="` and `"...>`. I used the Search and Replace function of the SublimeText editor to clean the code. My regular expression:

- Find: `<img alt="(.)"([a-z\d\s="-:;]+)>`
- Replace: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

RandomDude's right. This does solve the problem! However, I had to change the regex because now the image tags are a bit different:

```
<img crossorigin="anonymous" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" alt="" draggable="false" class="b38 emoji wa i0jNr selectable-text copyable-text" data-plain-text="" style="background-position: 0px -20px;">
```

The new lazy regular expression is:

- Find: `<img[\w\d\s="-:;]+alt="([^"]*)"[\w\d\s="-:;]+emoji[^>]*>`
- Replace: `$1`

I am also making sure, that we are handling an emoji just in case.